# Suddenly seeing lots of first chance exceptions in the output window of my ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, exception, visual-studio-2012

All of a sudden, I'm seeing floods of first chance exceptions in the VS.NET Output window.

There are 3 of us working on the project. We've all updated our code to the latest in SVN and I'm the only one seeing all the exceptions, so the issue is not our app, but I suspect, some setting that I accidentally triggered in VS.NET.

If I right click the Output window, "Exception Messages" is checked. It always has been and is for my co-workers, so that's not the issue.

I cannot see any options in `Tools/Options/Debugging` that could be responsible. I suspect I probably just accidentally hit some accelerator key combo that did it. These appear to be perfectly normal first chance exceptions (like setting a property in a dynamic object for the first time causing a RuntimeBindingException). The app seems to operate just fine. But the flood of messages is annoying and makes debug output hard to follow.

By far the most common exception is an `ArgumentException` with the message, `"A property with the name 'UriTemplateMatchResults' already exists."`
We use WCF very heavily (but no REST) and have a number of WCF services that our app communicates with, so I'm assuming that's just standard WCF stuff because the calls are all working fine.

Can anyone think of anything I might have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the source of the problem. As I suspected, it was something I had accidentally done, but I'm not sure when or exactly how. Hopefully this solution will help others.

The solution was `Tools/Options/Debugging` in the `General` section, I had somehow unchecked `Enable Just My Code`. I'm not sure how I unchecked it. That fixed the problem.